# Dynamic Filter using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to make the filter above the table "Show Filter" to filter the table real time. For example when the user change the value on the age input the table will change accordingly without any submitting. But I don't have any idea how can I do that. The HTML code for the table is this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover data-display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Religion</th>
        <th>Knowledge Level</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="studentInfo" items="${ studentInfo }" varStatus="i">
        <c:if test="${ studentInfo.graduate eq false }">
            <tr>
            <td>${ i.count }</td>
            <td><a href="#">${ studentInfo.name }</a></td>
            <td>${ studentInfo.age }</td>
            <td>${ studentInfo.gender }</td>
            <td>${ studentInfo.religion }</td>
            <td>${ studentInfo.knowledgeLevel }</td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: please share a generated html sample and the filter markup alos

Comment: Try something first, then get back to us.

Comment: I might suggest list.js - http://listjs.com/

Comment: there are numerous table sorting/filtering plugins for this

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't know yet how do I start the code for the filtering.

Comment: @Daedalus I'm asking here because I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to use the jquery datatables plugin, it's simple to use

http://datatables.net/

to use it make sure you have your headers in  tags and body in  tags, then just have the following to set up

```
        var oTable = $("#yourtableID").dataTable({
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sUrl": "IFYOUWANTOTHERLANGUAGE.txt"
                },
                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "iDisplayLength": 20,
                "aLengthMenu": [[20, 40, 80, -1], [20, 40, 80, "All"]]
        });
```

Then when you want to filter, you can use fnFilter to do it, i'm attaching part of code as reference, please refer to website for detail

```
            if ( selected_val == "toplevel"){
                oTable.fnFilter( '^$', "6", true, false );
                //oTable.fnDraw()
            } else if (selected_val == "topall"){
                //alert("clearing");
                oTable.fnFilter("","6");
                oTable.fnDraw();
            } else {
                oTable.fnFilter("^"+selected_val+"$", "6", "true");
            }
```

Comment: Can you give me the link of the exact location of this snippet. I can't find in the site

Comment: go to http://datatables.net/api and scroll down to fnfilter, or you can go to http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html for the most basic example What I have past here is combination of few examples